# Why are tmux settings reset, and how to automatically reload them?

Tags: settings, tmux

Every time I reopen tmux, some of the settings in my .tmux.conf are reset, and I have to run `tmux source-file ~/.tmux.conf` to reapply them. Oddly, some settings are not reset.

For example, these survive across tmux sessions:

```
# Use | and - for splitting windows
bind-key | split-window -h
bind-key - split-window -v
```

These reset every session:

```
# Change default 'prefix' key to '`'
set prefix `
unbind-key C-b
bind-key ` send-prefix
```

Why the difference in behavior?

And is there a way to automatically reload .tmux.conf whenever a tmux session starts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set -g prefix `
```

Stops those commands from resetting.

Automatically reloading them is unnecessary if they don't reset, and the ones that reset here are the `set-prefix` (or "set-option") block because set-option is sensitive to "session mode". Without `-g`, set-option defaults to session mode. But since there's initially no tmux session to apply itself *to*, it doesn't work until .tmux.conf is re-sourced while in a new tmux session. From the `man` page,

> If -g is given, the global session or window option is set.

Setting it instead to the global session pre-applies the command to all new tmux sessions.